# Arch linux sound problem

Tags: arch-linux, audio

2 days before I started using arch linux. I've got some sound issues.

I've installed `alsa alsa-utils` etc., unmuted all channels with `alsamixer`. My user is in audio group.

I've also installed `pulseaudio` and started it with

```
pulseaudio --start
```

- Command

  ```
  speaker-test -c 2
  ```

  does not make any sounds.
- In `pavucontroll` (I'm using `i3` but I don't think its matter) it's show up my sound card and this jumping line that something its playing sounds on it.
- When I'm plugging headphones it's detecting it end switch sound device from speakers, but no sound either.
- `hwinfo --sound`  display this:

  ```
  20: PCI 1f.3: 0403 Audio device
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: nS1_.b28td23g3aB
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1f.3
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x9d71 "Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1043 "ASUSTeK Computer Inc."
  SubDevice: pci 0x1a00 
  Revision: 0x21
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xef528000-0xef52bfff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xef500000-0xef50ffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 130 (616 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d00009D71sv00001043sd00001A00bc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
  Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
  Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Info #1:
  Driver Status: snd_soc_skl is active
  Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_soc_skl"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  ```

Yesterday I put off my laptop turned on for maybe an hour and sounds started working, but only to the next reboot. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

If it worked maybe it's cause you plugged in and audio device that shifted your default card number.

If you want a fast and easy solution you can edit (or make) your /etc/asound.conf like this: 

`defaults.pcm.card n
defaults.ctl.card n`

Where n is your primary sound device number.

Type on your terminal:
`$ alsamixer` 
and press f6, it will show you every audio device plugged in. 
Use that number for your /etc/asound.conf

I've said this is a fast solution, if you boot your system with an external audio device plugged in it will probably shift the numbers. (while pluggin it after booting won't)

for more infos: 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture